Firebase admin SDK throws internal server error when using the registration_token gotten from https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchImport
We are using Firebase to send push notifications to both Android and iOS devices. For iOS, we convert the APNs token received from the device into an FCM token using the https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchImport endpoint. However, when using the registration token returned from the batch import, we occasionally encounter an "internal server error" from Firebase. The notifications are delivered successfully at times, but they also fail intermittently.
Is this a common issue, or are there any known solutions or best practices to resolve this?
Things we tried.

Used the firebase admin SDK to send a notification with the registration token retrieved from https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchImport after providing it with the device apn token. This throws internal server errors
Used the firebase console to send a test notification using the registration token retrieved from https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchImport after providing it with the device apn token. This seems to work fine with no errors

